# Определить что фигура - квадрат, при произвольном порядке точек-аргументов

Tags: java, алгоритм, геометрия

У меня задача определить что фигура образующаяся из точек является квадратом, или нет: `boolean isFoursquare()`. Но условие задачи в том что порядок точек которые заходят в класс фигуры через конструктор не известен `Foursquare(final Point... points)`, понятно что их четыре, но точки могут быть отправлены в любом порядке. И алгоритм от этого ломаться не должен.

Выяснить есть ли у нас 4 равные стороны у меня вроде получилось, но вот определить какие из шести отрезков являются диагоналями чтобы их сравнить, что-то не выходит.

Помогите реализовать метод `boolean diagonalsIsEquals()`.

За конструктивную критику по выбранному пути решения, также буду благодарен.

Код фигуры:

```
public class Figure {
    private final Point[] points;

    public Figure(final Point... points) {
        if (points.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.diagonals = new double[2];
        this.points = points;
    }

    public boolean isFoursquare() {
        final double[] ways = new double[6];
        int waysCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = (i + 1); j < 4; j++) {
                ways[waysCount++] =
                        this.getLength(
                                this.points[j], this.points[i]
                        );
            }
        }

        return this.fourEqualsSidesIsExist(ways) && this.diagonalsIsEquals();
    }

    private double getLength(final Point fst, final Point scd) {
        final double length =
                Math.sqrt(
                        Math.pow(scd.getX() - fst.getX(), 2) +
                                Math.pow(scd.getY() - fst.getY(), 2)
                );

        if (length >= 0) {
            return length;
        }

        return length * (-1D);
    }

    private boolean fourEqualsSidesIsExist(final double[] segments) {
        int equalsCounter = 1;
        double val;
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
            val = segments[i];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < segments.length; j++) {
                if (segments[j] == val) {
                    equalsCounter++;
                    if (equalsCounter == 4) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            equalsCounter = 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean diagonalsIsEquals() {
        //Вот тут как-то надо выяснить какие из 6 отрезков 
        //получившихся из 4 точек, являются диагоналями фигуры.
    }
}
```

Это точка:

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: сравнивать **модуль** разницы координат - либо 0, либо все равны

Comment: А не проще тупо сосчитать все 6 длин, отсортировать их по возрастанию и проверить, что первое равно четвёртому, а пятое - шестому? Какая тебе разница, кто диагональ, а кто не очень?

Comment: @Akina гениально!

Comment: @Akina этого не достаточно - а что если на входе будет ромб ? для него тоже будет 1ая сторона равнятся 4ой, а 5я 6ой - надо ещё углы проверить что прямые

Comment: @ampawd не почему если диагонали равны и все стороны равны это 100% квадрат.

Comment: @Павел а, точно, извиняюсь, про диагонали забыл

Comment: @ampawd да все отлично, спасибо большое, вы главное идею подали, а то сам я что-то перегрелся, оформите как ответ что-бы я принять его смог.

Comment: @Павел я думаю ответ должен оформить тот кто дал эту идею, это был Akina

Comment: @Akina добавьте ваш ответ чтобы я мог принять.

Comment: Не стоит использовать медленную функцию `pow` для возведения в квадрат. Просто перемножьте два числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посчитать все 6 длин, отсортировать их по возрастанию, и проверить, что первое равно четвёртому, а пятое - шестому.

Comment: Лучше делать это с _квадратами_ длин, чтобы не вычислять ненужный и медленный корень.

Comment: @VladD Да, конечно. Я дал только направление, идею, так сказать...